# Is it neccessary to call app.delete() at the end of calling admin.initializeApp() in firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am writing a cloud function in which i am creating or initializing firebase app in a for loop with new names, my question is that , is it necessary to call app.delete() function on every instance or not?

```
 snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    counter++;
    // console.log(counter," in first");
    // console.log(doc.id, " is the doc ID");
    var home = doc.get('home');//e.g: hyperoffice 
    var switches = doc.get('switches');
    var action = doc.get('action');//ON or OFF
    var repeat=doc.get('repeat');// true or false

    try {
      // console.log("home ", home, " switches ", switches);
      let defapp = admin.initializeApp({ databaseURL: databaseUrl }, `${home}${counter}`);
      var databaseUrl = `https://${home}.firebaseio.com/`;
      switches.forEach(s => {
        let dbRef = admin.database(defapp).ref(`Controls/${s}`);
        dbRef.once("value").then(val => {
          var data = val.val();
          //   console.log("this is data", data);
          var payload_on = data.payload_on;
          var payload_off = data.payload_off;
          let valRef = admin.database(defapp).ref(`Controls/${s}/value`);
          if (action === "ON") {
            // on the device
            return valRef.set(payload_on);
          }
          else if (action === "OFF") {
            //off the device
            return valRef.set(payload_off);

          } else {
            console.log("Undefined action field in firestore");

          }
          return null;
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log("Error", err);
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Eroor: ", error);
    }
    finally {
      console.log("in finally block 67");

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you don't have to, but you will leak a lot of memory over time, and your function might crash in a future invocation.  Your function should always clean up unused memory before it terminates.  This means that you should delete any initialized apps, unless you want to use that exact same app instance in a future invocation.

Comment: what happens after the function terminates? What happens to the memory , enlighten me.

Comment: That's a whole different question that you should probably post separately here, if you're still unsure after you watch this video series to understand how Cloud Functions works.  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLm9A9rcHb1IkyQUu6QwbjdM